# Issue with viewing data transformation with PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I am currently trying to process data for a simple network. This is the code I entered:

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSYRs.png)

I keep getting this error message but can't find any syntax problems or anyone else with this issue, I'm guessing it's something to do with my vienv because I've seen tutorials of people with no issues and that exact code. It's possible I haven't imported a package into my IDE and I am using anaconda and PyCharm if that helps.

Anyway, this is the error message I keep getting.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz2Bo.png)

Comment: Ps, I changed the for loop from 'data' to 'i' between when I took the screenshots but the message was the same otherwise.

Comment: Please copy-paste the code and errors instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `transforms.ToTensor()` instead of `transforms.ToTensor` when passing to `transforms.Compose`.